# How can I find a variable with prompt in javascript?

Tags: javascript

with the function zoekAuto I want to if I say in the Prompt Maikel it says Maikel - 0. if you add fgvhj I want it to say thet it doesn't exist.

there is an error in this code but I cant find it.

```
var vrienden = ["Maikel", "Anna", "Peter", "Savannah"];

function toon() {
    document.getElementById("p7").innerHTML = vrienden + "  " + vrienden.length;
}

document.getElementById("p7").innerHTML = vrienden;
var vrienden = [" Maikel", " Anna", " Peter", " Savannah"];

function voegToe() {
    var vriend = prompt("Please enter your name:")

    vrienden.push(vriend);
    toon();

    document.getElementById("but").innerHTML = "toon lijst " + vrienden.length;
}

function toonFor() {
    document.getElementById("p6").innerHTML = "";

    lengteLijst = vrienden.length;
    for (i = 0; i < lengteLijst; i++) {
        document.getElementById("p6").innerHTML += i + " --- " + vrienden[i] + "<br>";
    }
}

function zoekauto() {
    var zoekString = prompt("welke naam zoek je???")
    var nr = vrienden.indexOf(zoekString);

    lengteLijst = vrienden.length;
    for (i = 0; i < lengteLijst; i++) {
        if (zoekString == vrienden[i]) {
            document.getElementById("p5").innerHTML += i + " -- gevonden " + nr + "<br>";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("p5").innerHTML = zoekString + " is niet gevonden";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Presently very unclear what you're asking. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I didn't check all the code, but when a correct value is found in the loop, you've to break the loop, so that the next incorrect value won't override the already found value.

Comment: Why do you redefine `vrienden` with a new array whose values all have a space in front of them? `var vrienden = [" Maikel", " Anna", " Peter", " Savannah"];`

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem.

Comment: There are some extra spaces in your array elements which  you need to remove before using `.indexOf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below function . There are some spaces in your array elements so you have to remove them to match with the actual value supplied in prompt

```js
var vrienden = ["Maikel", "Anna", "Peter", "Savannah"];

function zoekauto(){
            var zoekString = prompt ("welke naam zoek je???")
            var nr = vrienden.indexOf(zoekString);
              
            if(nr > -1){
              document.getElementById("p5").innerHTML += " -- gevonden " + nr + "<br>"; 
            }
             else{
               document.getElementById("p5").innerHTML = zoekString + " is niet gevonden";
             }             
        }
        
 zoekauto();
```

```html
<p id="p5"></p>
```